# Angular calculate percentage in the HTML

Tags: javascript, angularjs, number-formatting, angularjs-interpolate

I am trying to display a percentage value in my HTML as follows:

```
<td> {{ ((myvalue/totalvalue)*100) }}%</td>
```

It works but sometimes it gives a very long decimal which looks weird. How do I round it off to 2 digits after the decimal? Is there a better approach to this?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use the [`toFixed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) method of `Number`.

```
((myValue/totalValue)*100).toFixed(2)
```

Comment: This works better (At least in ease of implementation) than the percentage pipe

Answer (score 29):

You could use a filter, like this one below by [jeffjohnson9046](https://gist.github.com/jeffjohnson9046/9470800)

The filter makes the assumption that the input will be in decimal form (i.e. 17% is 0.17).

```
myApp.filter('percentage', ['$filter', function ($filter) {
  return function (input, decimals) {
    return $filter('number')(input * 100, decimals) + '%';
  };
}]);
```

Usage:

```
<tr ng-repeat="i in items">
   <td>{{i.statistic | percentage:2}}</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 7):

I often use [the built-in 'number' filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/number) for that purpose;

```
<span>{{myPercentage | number}}</span>
```

For 2 decimals:

```
<span>{{myPercentage | number:2}}</span>
```

For 0 decimal;

```
<span>{{myPercentage | number:0}}</span>
```

Answer (score 4):

Inside your controller.js (angular.js 1.x) or app.component.ts (angular2) calculate a percentage (logic) of a total value with a another value like this.

```js
this.percentage = Math.floor(this.myValue / this.value * 100);
```

Then show the percentage in the html.

```
<p>{{percentage}}%</p>
```

Simple Math Example: 3/10*100 = 30%. If `myValue` is 3 and `value` is 10  your result will be 30. Use Javascript's built in `Math.floor()` function to round the number and remove the decimal.

Answer (score 3):

You could use Angular  [percent](https://angular.io/api/common/PercentPipe)  pipe for this.

Simplest solution in a single line within HTML using Angular would be as follows:

```
<td> {{ myvalue/totalvalue | percent:'2.0-2' }}</td>
```

If myvalue = 4 & totalvalue = 10, then result will be displayed as

```
40.00%
```

for respective HTML element.

Comment: That doesn't appear available in AngularJS (which is what the tags specify).

Answer (score 1):

Use ng-bind that would not show curly braces until the expression resolved.

**Html**

```
<td ng-bind="roundedPercentage(myValue, totalValue) + '%'"></td>
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.roundedPercentage = function(myValue, totalValue){
   var result = ((myValue/totalValue)*100)
   return Math.round(result, 2);
}
```