# How to differentiate Rs and % values?

Tags: angularjs, logic, shopping-cart, angularjs-ng-repeat

In my shopping cart app i am getting offers in price and percentage from server.
I need to differentiate the price value and percentage values with Rs. and %.

Here is my code in controller:

```
if(result.type == 'Price'){                                     
                                    $scope.invoice_amt = $scope.invoice_amt - result.offer ;                                                                                    
                                    } 
                                    else if(result.type == 'Percentage'){                                     
                                    $scope.invoice_amt = $scope.invoice_amt * result.offer/100;                                                                                    
                                    }
```

I am getting the value in HTML as {{invoice_amt}}
How to show the offers in rs. and percentage.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use currency filter, this below sample will print in **Rupees ( ₹ )**

```
   Invoice Price<span>{{invoice_amt | currency:"&#8377;"}}</span>
```

Percentage related point is mentioned in below link

[Angular calculate percentage in the html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29989200/angular-calculate-percentage-in-the-html)

Use one more variable in your scope to check the **type** and based on that write the logic. Refer the Angular documentation
 https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/currency